# Is this flea beetle damage on this hollyhock?

Tags: pest-control, pests, pest-damage

Here's a picture of a hollyhock. It's been covered with holes like this all year (and the ones last year were, too, all year). As a side note, I gave it potassium for the yellowing of the leaves, twice (once just before I took this picture).

[image]

So, my question is, are these holes caused by flea beetles? I've never actually seen any flea beetles on them. Hollyhocks in other areas of my western Idaho town have similar problems. Ours used to be worse than this.

How do I stop these holes from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These holes are probably caused by the hollyhock weevil - I'm not quite sure where you are, but they are endemic in Colorado and other areas of the States. Remove the seed pods as they form - some may overwinter in those and emerge next year to cause damage. Treatment, if you don't want to use an appropriate pesticide spray, is to shake the plant - this should make them fall off and you then destroy them. Otherwise, buy an appropriate pesticide and use according to the instructions.

As for the yellow/orange markings, that looks remarkably like Hollyhock Rust - if there are pustules under the leaves, then that's what it is. Control of this fungal infection is difficult, and its best to buy rust resistant cultivars of the plant. You may find a fungal spray that's suitable for use in your area though, its worth checking.